# Select only records of the current week from Mysql Database Timestamp Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, eloquent

I want to get only the records from monday to friday of the current week, but i'm having a hard time thinking and researching ways on how to do it, I found some ways on the internet but its so hard to understand for a newbie like me, so here is my code:

```
         $myquery=DB::table('attendances')
        ->leftJoin('employees', 'attendances.user_id', '=', 'employees.id')
        ->where('user_id', '=', $employee->id)

        //I want to do something like this one
         ->WHERE WEEK(`date`) = WEEK(NOW()  

        ->orderBy('attendances.date','asc')->get();
```

I implement some of the answers like this

```
         $myquery=DB::table('attendances')
        ->leftJoin('employees', 'attendances.user_id', '=', 'employees.id')
        ->where("WEEKOFYEAR(`date`)", "=", "WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())")
        ->where('user_id', '=', $employee->id)
        ->orderBy('attendances.logon','asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `whereBetween` with two `Carbon` date instances:

```
->whereBetween('date', [
    Carbon\Carbon::parse('last monday')->startOfDay(),
    Carbon\Carbon::parse('next friday')->endOfDay(),
])
```

If you want to find all record in the current month, use this:

```
->whereBetween('date', [
    Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(),
    Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfMonth(),
])
```

Comment: How about all records in current month?

Comment: If today is monday, then this returns the monday from the week before, which is not OK. It is better to use Carbon::now()->startOfWeek() and Carbon::now()->endOfWeek().

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use [`WEEKOFYEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) instead of just `WEEK`, which gets the current week index in a year. So two dates in the same week will return the same `WEEKOFYEAR`. In normal SQL it would look like:

```
... WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
```

And in laravel:

```
->where("WEEKOFYEAR(`date`)", "=", "WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sir, but I get error 50 on the laravel code

Comment: How did you integrate the answer?

Comment: @user3177305 In the code what is ``date``? Is it defined anywhere? Try adding a string like `'2014-01-01'`, does that still lead to a 500 error?

Comment: still getting the error sir, if i used WhereOr then there is no error but the output is wrong

Comment: the date is a column in mysql database, its a timestamp

Comment: If it's a timestamp convert it to a Date. Laravel might be treating the first attribute as if it needs to be a column. How about trying a raw SQL: `->whereRaw('WEEKOFYEAR(DATE(\`date\`)) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())');`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like

`` ->where('WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))', '=', 'WEEK(NOW())')
->where('DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))', '>=', 2)
->where('DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))', '<=', 6) ``

Comment: Consider wrapping the query in a try/catch so the error is more obvious. Also, I updated the query to account for the fact that you are using unix timestamps as the column as you stated in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data for the current week excluding saturday and sunday:

```
$query->where(DB::Raw('week(date)'), '=', Carbon::now()->weekOfYear)
      ->where(function($query){
             return $query->where(DB::Raw('day(date)'),'<>',Carbon::SUNDAY)
                          ->orWhere(DB::Raw('day(date)'), '<>',Carbon::SATURDAY); });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? (Eloquent / Laravel 5.6)

```
Model::whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('Y'));
```

It is well documented and works great: [Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: This is useful for month range, but doesn't solve question.