# Laravel 5.2 Display each users posts they've made this week as count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display a list of all the users and how many posts they've each made this week, and how many they've made last week, inside of a form

I've used a hasMany relation between the two tables and the relationship it's self is working.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\applications', 'user_id');
```

inside of the view what I have that's displaying the post count is

```
{{$user->applications->count()}}
```

The main thing I'm stuck on is the SQL Query or using Carbon inside of the controller function to achieve this.

If anyone has done this before your help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209202/select-only-records-of-the-current-week-from-mysql-database-timestamp-laravel

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to count posts for many users, eager load the data and use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```
User::withCount(['applications' => function($q) {
    $q->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()]);
}])->get();
```

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models